# game models that stand in grass

Tags: opengl, graphics

The open source game [Glest](http://glest.org) has models that feel detached from the ground that they sit on because of the hard edges.  In real life, grass is not flat!

What are the options and recommendations for breaking up the hard edges where the meshes of the models meet the terrain?  How do other games do it?  What are the options on a sliding scale of rendering performance?

[image: A screenshot from glest]

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is probably helpful here.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/game-models-that-stand-in-grass <-- 0 views

Answer (score 2):

Actually the best way to stop something looking detached from the ground is consistent lighting and shadowing.  Try casting a shadow onto the ground to start with and you'll find things instantly look a lot better.

Grass rendering is a whole different ballgame.  There are numerous different methods, I'd suggest starting here (Found by searching for "Grass Rendering" on google!)

http://www.gamerendering.com/category/vegetation/